# NgRx - Selecting AppState in effects

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have an effect in my NgRx application where it needs to dispatch an action as a "side-effect" along with the main final action that the effect should dispatch. But this "side-effect action" depends on a state key that I need to select from the AppState.

I'm afraid that the way I implemented is not correct, since **the side effect action is always being dispatched when the AppState key changes**. I know that using the NgRx selectors creates a stream of Observables, but I don't know what is the correct implementation to this.

Here is my effect:

```
createNewTask$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(fromAgendaActions.createNewTask),
  concatMap(action => this.agendaService.createNewTask(action.payload)
    .pipe(
      tap(() => {
        this.store.select(selectCurrentDate).subscribe(currentDate => {
          if(moment(action.payload.followUpDate).isBefore(moment().startOf('date'))) {
            this.store.dispatch(fromAgendaActions.getOverdueTasks());
          }
          if(moment(currentDate).startOf('date').isSame(moment(action.payload.followUpDate))) {
            this.store.dispatch(fromAgendaActions.getTasks({ payload: { date: moment(currentDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY') }}));
          }
            });
      }),
      map(() => fromAgendaActions.createNewTaskSuccess()),
      catchError(() => of({ type: fromAgendaActions.AgendaActionsTypes.CreateNewTaskFail, error: 'error' }))
    )
)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried but the following should be ok:

```
createNewTask$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromAgendaActions.createNewTask),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectCurrentDate)),
    concatMap(([action, currentDate]) =>
      this.agendaService.createNewTask(action.payload).pipe(
        concatMap(() => {
          const actions = [];
          if (
            moment(action.payload.followUpDate).isBefore(
              moment().startOf('date')
            )
          ) {
            actions.push(fromAgendaActions.getOverdueTasks());
          }

          if (
            moment(currentDate)
              .startOf('date')
              .isSame(moment(action.payload.followUpDate))
          ) {
            actions.push(
              fromAgendaActions.getTasks({
                payload: { date: moment(currentDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY') },
              })
            );
          }

          actions.push(fromAgendaActions.createNewTaskSuccess());

          return from(actions).map(a => of(a));
        }),
        catchError(() =>
          of({
            type: fromAgendaActions.AgendaActionsTypes.CreateNewTaskFail,
            error: 'error',
          })
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)